# How to change javadoc comments language when generate java from wsdl with CXF wsdl2java?

Tags: cxf, wsdl2java

I generated java sources from wsdl file using CXF wsdl2java command :

```
wsdl2java -impl -server -d <path_to_wsdl> <path_to_generated_java_source>
```

but the generated comments are in French. How is possible to change the comments language (I want the comments in English). I could not find the option in [CXF wsdl2java Documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html).

Thanks very much in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not yet an option to change the language, see [JAXB jira issue](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-1001). If the generated output language (e.g. german) causes encoding problems you can at least specify the encoding of the generated files (since version 2.5.4):

```
wsdl2java ... -encoding UTF-8 ....
```

Comment: I had a problem related to this issue: because the language was German (with lot of special characters) and the encoding was not UTF-8, I had `unmappable character for encoding UTF-8`. This was solved setting the encoding of CXF: in configuration I added encoding `<configuration> ... <encoding>UTF-8</encoding> ... </configuration>`

Answer (score 2):

In the batch script you call (like wsdl2java.bat), as well as in the unix shell script file, Java is called with some parameters. There you can set the parameters for country (user.country) and language (user.language).
So the line would looks like this:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -Xmx128M -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Dkava-endorsed.dirs=[...]
```

When you start the converting again, the comments are generated in English (or what ever language you define here).
Worked for me on Windows. Should work on other OS as well, as you directly set Java parameters.

**EDIT:**

In fact it's enough to only use *-Duser.language=US_en* or just *-Duser.language=en*.

Comment: seem option can't be passed through arguments because wsdl2java is a plugin, however option can be passed through environment variable `_JAVA_OPTION=-Duser.language=en`

Answer (score 0):

WSDLToJava use operating system language to generate comments.

for me i am executing WSDLToJava class using ant script,
the solution for me was to add this

```
<java classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="true">
    <sysproperty key="user.language" value="en"/> <!-- Set language to English -->
    <arg value="-bareMethods"/> .....
```